# Websphere Migration from was7 to was9

Tags: migration, websphere, middleware

Planning to Migrate the Websphere from 7.0 to 9 and 8.5 to 9. 
Can anyone help me getting the detailed Process

Migration here is "In place". (Migration will be done on the same servers, where the old Installation are in)

if at all any migration tools need to be used, please provide the clear info on them. 
any documental references, or any video references for the questioner is appreciated.

OS used : RHEL 
CUrrent version: WAS 7x and 8.5
Migrating to : WAS 9.0

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the planning phase, I'd strongly suggest you to consider migrating to WebSphere Liberty instead of traditional WAS v9. All these migration tools (toolkit for binaries, Eclipse migration toolkit) support both migration scenarios.

Choosing Liberty might be a bit more work at the beginning, but you will gain more deployment flexibility and speed up future development. Liberty is also much better fitted for any cloud/containers environments, as it is much more lightweight, so in the future, if you would like to move to containers, it would be much easier.

Check this tutorial [Migrate traditional WebSphere apps to WebSphere Liberty on IBM Cloud Private by using Kubernetes](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/garage/content/course/websphere-on-cloud-private/0), although it shows the steps to migrate to Liberty on ICP, beginning is the same - analyzing of the application whether they are fit for Liberty and migrating. If you don't have access to IBM Cloud or ICP, you can use stand alone version of the Transformation Advisor that was released recently - [IBM Cloud Transformation Advisor](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/garage/practices/learn/ibm-transformation-advisor).

Having said all that, some apps include old or proprietary traditional WebSphere APIs and in that case it may be easier and cheaper to temporary migrate them to WAS v9, and modernize in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're in the very beginning stages of doing this migration. Therefore, I highly recommend you take some time to plan this out, especially to figure out the exact steps you'll be taking and how you'll handle something going wrong. For WebSphere, there is a [collection of documents](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27008724) from IBM that discuss planning and executing the upgrade. Look around there for documentation on the tools and step by step guides for different kinds of topologies. The step by step guide for an in place migration of a cell is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.migration.nd.doc/ae/tmig_migrate_cells_commandline.html).

You should make sure to take good backups before you start the process so you can restore back to before the migration if you need to.

In addition to doing the upgrade, an important part is to also make sure your applications are going to work on the new version if you haven't already. IBM provides [this tool](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-Migration_Toolkit_for_Application_Binaries) to scan applications and identify potential issues that developers will have to fix. There is documentation for the tool at that link as well.